# Como obter todos os métodos em que uma classe está usando

Tags: java, reflexão

Preciso encontrar uma forma de encontrar todos os métodos em que uma classe está usando (preste a atenção,não são os métodos declarados nela).
EX:

```
public class Bondia{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("oi");
    System.out.println(new Random().nextInt(10));
    }
}
```

Nessa classe, por exemplo, eu preciso listar os métodos:

- `System.out.println();`
- `java.util.Random.nextInt();`
- e de preferência o construtor também (`new java.util.Random()`);

Alguém conhece uma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Isso daí não é algo que reflexão simples resolva. Precisa de algo mais complicado, que faça análise de bytecode. Talvez alguma ferramenta tal como ASM ou javassist.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa de StackTrace que pode fazer isso, mas acredito que a melhor maneira seria usando javassist.

Comment: Use a ferramenta do JDK [javap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/javap.html). É disassemble de classes. Ex: no shell digite na linha de comando `$ javap -c java.lang.Object`

Answer (score -5):

Olá, não entendi muito bem, mas se você quiser pode fazer diferente, criar a classe Bondia e depois no main iniciar ela. Se for sobre todos os metodos da classe Random, pode verificar a documentação.

Comment: Ele quer listar quais os métodos não pertencentes a classe uma instancia usa.